# How to safely reconfigure gcc on my Linux system?

Tags: linux, centos, gcc

I am trying to install a program ([github.com/zhenglz/dockingML](https://github.com/zhenglz/dockingML)) on CentOS 6.10 and at the end of the installation, it gave an error saying that Glibc-2.14 is necessary. I upgraded the current Glibc and this time the error below occurred:

- These critical programs are missing or too old: gcc * Check the INSTALL file for required versions.

I upgraded the gcc and tried to configure again. However, the same error persists. Hence I read the INSTALL file as it suggests, and I see this section:

> You may also need to reconfigure GCC to work with the new library. The easiest way to do that is to figure out the compiler switches to make it work again (‘-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-linux.so.2’ should work on GNU/Linux systems) and use them to recompile gcc.

So should I go to where gcc is built and do:

```
$ ./configure -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

?? Do I understand the instructions correctly? If so, then how will I be able to configure only gcc and not the other executable files as they are all in the same folder? (e.g., gcc-5, git, idle, python, python-build.. etc.) The directory is something like: `home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/gcc`.

I'm asking this because GNU compiler and GCC are fundamental in Linux system, and I'm not sure if those are the correct steps.

Comment: Which program are you trying to install? Upgrading `Glibc` is not advisable (unless you are a Linux guru). You should instead upgrade your entire distribution.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch actually this package:  https://github.com/zhenglz/dockingML

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch you mean upgrading centos from 6.10 to a newer version?

Comment: Perhaps. However, don't comment your question but edit it instead. BTW, you should not install Glibc like you probably did

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks, so I edited. You mean I shouldn't have installed it thru linuxbrew?

Comment: `glibc`, i.e. your `libc.so`, is literally the corner stone of most Linux distributions. I recommend upgrading your distro instead (or at least use some `chroot`ed environment)